# GroupingStore order groups by total in each group

Tags: extjs

Team(s) - I am using Extjs v. 3x and have the entire grouping using the grouping store working perfectly but what I can't seem to figure out is how to render the actual groups (not the underlying records) based on the total in each group.

```
requestGrid = new Ext.ux.SearchPageingGridPanel({
    height:500
    //,title:'Application User Listing'
    ,store: trackerStore
    ,columns: userColumns // or define inline via columns
    ,collapsible:false
    //,stateId : "requestsdffasdfd"
    ,header: true
    ,view: new Ext.grid.GroupingView({
        forceFit:true,
        showGroupName: true,
        enableNoGroups:false,
        enableGroupingMenu:false,
        startCollapsed: true,
        autoFill: true,
        groupMode: 'display',
        hideGroupedColumn: false,
        groupTextTpl: ' ({[values.rs.length]} {[values.rs.length > 1 ? "Items" : "Item"]}) {text}'
    })
    ,renderTo: 'grid-paneling'

});
```

The above is my code using the GroupingView and what I want to do is show the group ordering based on values.rs.lenght.

So for example: if I have 3 groups.

(3 Items) Column Group Name
(6 Items) Column Group Name
(2 Items) Column Group Name

I want to display in this order.

(6 Items) Column Group Name
(3 Items) Column Group Name
(2 Items) Column Group Name

Answer (score 2):

Here is working sample: http://jsfiddle.net/GzsDW/2/

What I've done is basically create a column with data formated in that way it sorts like you want. In my example the columns name is `industry-count`. Values for that column are counted in `datachanged` event. After everything is set, there is `applySort` call. And that's it.

Here is `datachanged` event code:

```
datachanged: function() {
    var count = {};
    var field = this.groupField.split('-')[0];

    // count group values first
    this.data.each(function(r) {
        var v = r.get(field);
        count[v] = 1 + (count[v] || 0);
    }, this);
    // create string like 99999998|Value and put it into industry-count field
    this.data.each(function(r) {
        var v = r.get(field);
        r.data[this.groupField] = (99999999 - count[v]) + '|' + v;
    }, this);
    // sort by new values
    this.applySort();
}
```

Comment: Cheers! This solved a semi-related problem I was having.